# How to enable short_open_tags on DotCloud?

Tags: php, dotcloud, php-shorttags

I'm migrating my code from another PaaS provider to DotCloud, but I got a small headache: I'm not finding in the documentation where I can change the php.ini settings to enable short open tags, something my entire codebase relies on.

How can I set this?

Comment: Just tried `<?php ini_set('short_open_tag', '1'); ?>` at the beginning of the index file, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding your own php.ini file?
http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/php/#configuring-php

Comment: duh. the docs are confusing. I was looking for something under platforms or tutorials. thanks!